# SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD) not working with thread ID

Tags: c++, windows, dll, hook

I have a dll that gets called by a process and now I would like to implement an input check in the dll to react on certain inputs that occur in the application.

[`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a [`KeyboardProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function seemed like a possible solution so I implemented it.

This is roughly how the code in the dll looks like:

```
static HHOOK hhk = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{  
    if(code == HC_ACTION && ((DWORD)lParam & 0x80000000) == 0)  // if there is an incoming action and a key was pressed
    {
       switch(wParam)
       {
       case VK_SPACE:
          printf("Space was pressed\n");
          break;
       }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hhk, code, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        if(AllocConsole()){
            freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);  // redirect output to console for debugging
        }
        printf("Dll loaded, lastError = %i\n", GetLastError());
        printf("lastError = %i\n", GetLastError());
        // sidenote: for some reason the first GetLastError() returns 0 while the second one returns 6 (invalid handle)

        hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, keyboardProc, hModule, GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
    else if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        printf("\nCleaning up...");
        FreeConsole();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

However nothing happens (or gets printed) in the Console window when I press any key. It doesn't even seem like the `keyboardProc` function is accessed at any time.

It *does* work though when I pass `NULL` instead of `GetCurrentThreadId()` to `SetWindowsHookEx()`. 
But this causes the hook to work globally meaning that whenever I press a key in another application, a Console window pops up (because the dll gets called again) and he checks for key inputs there.
Obviously this is not desired and I would like to make this work with only the process that originally called the dll.

I already checked if `GetCurrentThreadId()` returns a valid ID and it seems to be indeed the main thread ID of the process that initially called the dll (checked with Process Explorer).

So now my question is what could be the problem and more importantly, what can I do to make it working?

Comment: The DLL gets called by default from the program. However I do not have the source for the program, only the DLL. I have checked multiple times with Process Explorer if the Thread ID is correct and also tried to load it over the Process ID using this snippet -> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/78801/How-to-get-the-main-thread-ID-of-a-process-known-b

Comment: did you come over the problem? I got the exact same problem :(

Comment: Unfortunately no, any suggestions would still be very much appreciated (sry for the late reply).

Comment: I believe you are supposed to include a message loop in your app in order for this to work. 
while (GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
 {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }

Answer (score -1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

uint process_id;
uint thread_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, out process_id);
hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, a_KeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
```

I have used the code above to get the main thread_ID for a certain process. The good part is, the SetWindowsHookEx function gives a logical output. Unfortunately, the bad part is, if a key is pressed in the thread that has been hooked, the thread stops working.

In specific, the idHook parameter of SetWindowsHoookEx function was set to 2 (instead of 13) in my case for non-low-level keyboard events. It seems, at least to me, that LL corresponds to low-level, where keyboardProc should come with a WH_KEYBOARD instead of WH_KEYBOARD_LL.

I am not sure at this point how my response would be related to your question. Hopefully, we get what we need through discussion.